# How to get list of all users to follow

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

I have two tables USER and Relation_User how to get list all users I wanted to following them that already don't following me

```
User Table

Usid|name
---------
1 | Jack
2 | Bla
3 | Havi
4 | Tri

Relation_User

Rid|usid|fusid
--------------
1 | 1 | 2
2 | 2 | 1
3 | 3 | 2
4 | 1 | 4
```

Comment: can you show the result which you want to get from these tables?

Comment: Could you clarify the question? It's a bit hard to tell what you want. Adding expected output from the query would also help.

Comment: have u tried anything yet? (smells like homework)

Comment: what is usid amd fusid ?It is not very clear .

Comment: @Jenson :) is not home work is problemwork

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select usid, name from user u 
where u.usid <> @id and u.usid not in (
    select distinct fusid from relation_user where usid = @id
)
```